# Make subprocess.run() print a non-latin string on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

Running this code via subprocess.run() results in `UnicodeEncodeError` on Windows:

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(
    ["python", "-c", "print('Делавер')"],
    text=True,
    capture_output=True,
)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

Changing `text=True` to `encoding="utf8"` does not help.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: character maps to <undefined>
```

Strange, it is rather simple behavior to print a string, even with non-latin characters. I understnd the conflict is somewhere in making a conversion from utf8 to cp1251, but not  sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is best explained here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/105312.

The solution is `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` befor running the script.